# invalid use of incomplete type 'class QGraphicsRectItem'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create movable rectangle and here is my code.but following 3 errors appears.

```
invalid use of incomplete type 'class QGraphicsRectItem' rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);

forward declaration of 'class QGraphicsItem' class QGraphicsItem;

incomplete type 'QGraphicsItem' used in nested name specifier
```

without this line (`rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);`) program run without any error.

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>


namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *elipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QCursor>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(6);

    elipse = scene->addEllipse(10,10,100,100,blackPen,redBrush);
    rect = scene->addRect(-10,-10,100,100,blackPen,redBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: add `#include <QGraphicsRectItem>`  or `#include <QGraphicsItem>` to widget.h, that solves your problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you very much sir :) problem solved. Sir how can I identify such type of errors. Qt displaying error not helps to me to identify real problem.have any way to identify such errors

Comment: I recommend you include the header of each class you use so avoid this kind of silly problems.

Comment: Any time you ever see the compiler tell you that a type is "incomplete", it means that it has seen a forward declaration  e.g.

    class QGraphicsRectItem;

but hasn't seen the full class definition.  

So all you have to do is find the header file that contains the full class definition and be sure it is properly included.

Comment: @Joe thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `<QGraphicsRectItem>` class you are using in your code. Add it at the beginning like:

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem> //You missed
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
```